# PHP advanced custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This may be a basic question but i cant seem to find a correct solution.

In advanced custom fields I have set up a Field Group CD, in CD there are three fields, title, info, author and the group shows if the category = CD

Therefore when i make a new post with category CD I fill these three fields. There are 10 Posts in the CD categories.

Now the issue I am having is displaying all the posts on a page.

Here is the code I tried

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

       <?php query_posts( array(      'posts_per_page' => -1,      'cat' => '6',     'CD' => ( get_query_var('CD') ? get_query_var('CD') : 1 ), ));

            if (have_posts()) {
               while (have_posts()) {
                  the_post();
            get_post_meta();
                } // end while
                } // end if
            ?>


            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

This returned an error `Warning: Missing argument 1 for get_post_meta(), called in /Volumes/shared/Digital/_Websites/londonconchord/wp-content/themes/conchord/t-disc.php on line 25 and defined in /Volumes/shared/Digital/_Websites/londonconchord/wp-includes/post.php on line 1792`

I tried a different attempt

```
<p><?php query_posts( 'cat=6' ); 
      the_field('title');
      the_field('info');
      the_field('author'); ?></p>
```

I had more luck here as I was printing some information, however only the 1st post in the category and it kept repeating, i wanted all 10 posts and no repeat.

I think im close just looking for those final pointers

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution (Finally,) Hope this can help others

```
 <?php

           $args = array('cat' => 6);
           $category_posts = new WP_Query($args);

           if($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
              while($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
                 $category_posts->the_post();
        ?>
                <div class="article">
                <div class="articleinfo">
                <h3><?php the_field('title'); ?></h3>
                <?php the_field('author'); ?>
                <?php the_field('label'); ?>
                    </div>
           <img src="<?php the_field('cd_image'); ?>" height="200" width="200" alt="cd-image" />

            </div>

        <?php
              endwhile;
           else: 
        ?>

              Oops, there are no posts.

        <?php
           endif;
        ?>
```

Loops through all posts and pulls the ACF i needed

Answer (score 0):

Seems `get_post_meta()` has variables and your are missing it.

Like `get_post_meta($var)` expected but your are just calling `get_post_meta()`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're not querying properly I don't think.

You need to grab the field

```
get_field('YOUR FIELD NAME') );
```

Then loop through and grab what you need as a subfield.

```
the_sub_field('YOUR SUB FIELD');
```

Example

```
    <?php if(get_field('YOUR FIELD NAME')): while(has_sub_field('YOUR FIELD NAME')): ?>
        <img class="logo" src="<?php the_sub_field('logo'); ?>" />
        <h1><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></h1> 
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

For an example. Hope this helps... let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get ether of the solutions above to work, thank you though guys for your input,

here is my solution so far

```
<h3><?php the_field('title', 475); ?></h3>
                    <?php the_field('info', 475); ?>
                    <?php the_field('author', 475); ?>
                        </div>
               <img src="<?php the_field('cd_image', 475); ?>" height="200" width="200" alt="" />
```

Then I just repeated this and changed the id from 475 to others, now ive pulled in all the posts however the downfall is that any new posts i have to add in this code again.

Can i use a wp query to pull these 4 fields in a variable and then print that variable, then loop through the category until all posts are printed?